# Git, definition scope of branch

Tags: git, git-branch

As the merger with the other branches to define its borders in the overall chain of commits?
For example, a branch of the dev branch branches fix-001, there are several commits, then the fix-001 joins the dev. After that, the dev wants to see what commits are fix-001.

Best regards!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you didn't delete the branch `fix-001`, you can still look at it, merging doesn't destroy it in any way.

To do that, use either

```
gitk fix-001
```

or

```
git log fix-001
```

If you *did* delete it, then there is not much you can do. Except maybe trying to look at commit summaries.